# OpenCSV runtime error NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Date

Tags: java-11, opencsv, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm trying to read a CSV file into a Bean.  Everything compiles without issue, but when I run, I get the below Exception.

I don't think it's an issue with the code, most likely with one of the libraries that Apache is using.  I had a Date (java util) in the original class, but converted it to string just to see if that was the issue.  I even switched the project to Maven and added the opencsv dependency just to make sure I was getting the correct dependencies.  No luck... I did the google search and found that the issue was fixed at some point, but I'm not sure how to get the right code in place...

[ClassNotFound: java.sql.Date in JDK 11 in Pipeline Utility Steps](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54355?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   java/sql/Date     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.registerOther(ConvertUtilsBean.java:730)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.deregister(ConvertUtilsBean.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.(ConvertUtilsBean.java:161)
>     at
>   opencsv@4.6/com.opencsv.bean.ConverterPrimitiveTypes.(ConverterPrimitiveTypes.java:66)
>     at
>   opencsv@4.6/com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.determineConverter(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:608)
>     at
>   opencsv@4.6/com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.loadFieldMap(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:214)
>     at
>   opencsv@4.6/com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.setType(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:358)
>
> ** snip**

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

public class OpenBail {
    @CsvBindByName
    private String CourtCaseNumber;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String CourtBranch;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String EntityName;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ReceivedDate;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String PlaintiffTitle;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String DefendantTitle;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ReceiptNumber;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ReceiptEntityName;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String RoleTypeDesc;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ActionStatusDesc;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ActionTypeDesc;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String Address1;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String Address2;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String Address3;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String City;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String StateCode;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String ZipCode;

    @CsvBindByName
    private int OriginalAmount;

    @CsvBindByName
    private boolean isValidUSPS;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSAddress1;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSAddress2;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSAddress3;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSCity;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSStateCode;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String USPSZipCode;

// Removed Getter's and Setter's 
}
```

// Calling Code method

```
public static List<OpenBail> readOpenBailFile(String openBailFile){
Path myPath = Paths.get(openBailFile);

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(myPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<OpenBail> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<OpenBail>();
    strategy.setType(OpenBail.class);

        CsvToBean<OpenBail> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<OpenBail>(br)
                .withType(OpenBail.class)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                .build();

        List<OpenBail> openBailList = csvToBean.parse();

        return openBailList;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + "Caused By: " + e.getCause());
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your stack trace shows a mix of modular and non-modular code. It looks like "opencvs" has been migrated to a module but Apache BeansUtils has not. Can you summarize how this application is run? It might be that it needs `---add-modules java.sql` to help the code on the class path that needs it.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks, it is currently in Eclipse, the first time I'm using the bean libraries in OpenCSV.  I just starting using Java 11 (from Java 8), so I'm still getting used to the whole modules thing.  I'll try to add it to the project setup when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @AlanBateman Your comment solved the issue.  Post it as an answer so you can get credit for it.  Thanks!